# What is a bevel join of two lines exactly (Illustrator)?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector

When joining thick lines there are usually some options

- round
- miter
- bevel

In a bevel join, the joint is 'flat'. But what does that mean precisely?

There seem to be two options:

**Orthogonal**

The two points are orthogonal to their respective segments and half the thickness away from them:

[image: Ortho]

**Thickness**

The distance from the 'flat' to the center line is half the line thickness:

[image: Thickness]

Which of them is actually a true bevel-join? And is there a name for the other (I'm thinking it might be some kind of truncated miter).

Comment: Not quite sure what made the editor relate this post to adobe-illustrator. I don't even have the software :) I got to admit though, I was a bit at a loss when it came to finding tags for this question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Neither Adobe's PostScript(R) Manual, Second Edition nor W3C's [SVG manual](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/painting.html#StrokeProperties) describes the "Thickness" bevel.

Your "Orthogonal" bevel corresponds to the definition of "Bevel join" in both manuals, so I suppose that one would be considered the true bevel-join.

Neither manual calls it "Orthogonal".  The PostScript(R) manual describes the construction of the bevel as capping each of the two intersecting lines with a square butt cap, then filling in the resulting empty triangle, while the SVG manual simply has an illustration that appears to be the same as your "Orthogonal" join.

Comment: Yea, I made those words up :) The "thickness" one might be nothing more than inaccurate illustrations in manuals and such. Many thanks.